# Tags not stored when creating build def

Tags: tfs

I am using the TFS2018 API. I have the following code where I am creating a build definition and I am setting one tag item to the list of tags. But the tag is not stored for some reason. If I get the build definition after updating the tags list is empty.

```
 def.Tags.Add("MyTag");
 using (var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(uri, cred))
 {
       var t = buildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(def, teamProject);
       var result = t.Result;
 }

 var defs = GetBuildDefinitions(teamProject);
```

Any idea why the tag is not successfully stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def.Tags.Add("MyTag")` doesn't interact with TFS server, you should use the following code to [add a tag to a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#add-a-tag-to-a-build):

```
var myCredentials = new VssClientCredentials();
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/defaultCollection"), myCredentials);
var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
var tag = buildServer.AddBuildTagAsync("TeamProject",buildID, "my tag").Result;
```